# Is there a way to use URLFetchApp to behave like importData for CSV rresults

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

For various reasons (see question [Force the refresh of a Google Sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/164496/force-the-refresh-of-a-google-sheet)) I am trying to replace the use of importData in an app script with a custom function that leverages UrlFetchApp.fetch() retrieve a set of data from a remote host that is in CSV format.

I'm using the UrlFetchApp class to get the response with urlResponse.getContentText() followed by Utilities.parseCsv(), returning that result from my custom function.

This all works as expected with one difference that I'm trying to solve for.  Using importData to the same endpoint I get a result to my sheet that automatically detects and handles dates and number columns.  With my custom method, this does not happen so numbers are in as text. This creates issues with a summary sheet as their numeric values are expected.

Is there some other method or technique that I should be using to get the same result as I get with importData and that I get (by selecting the right option) by importing CSV from a file?

I created a new sheet - [CellarInventoryTestSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DEtYf9JBriFjLNZziI_GyDTQ5AhybjCNgKlKXwsccXg/edit?usp=sharing) that can be used to see the issue I'm describing. The first tab - "Login" has description and instructions. I also ran the sheet with the two functions and did a copy / paste special values only which shows the difference in the results. Let me know if this is useful.

Comment: Add a "minimum verifiable complete example" (code, instructions to run it, an a sample of the response retrieved by urlFetchApp, and the corresponding expected result).

Comment: I understand the ask, the data is being fetched from a site that requires authentication, so I'd need to include Id/pwd info so need to think about that. I can easily provide the output of two sheets that show the difference, but I don't think that will help you much. I'd be happy to share with you privately if that helps.

Comment: Not necessary to add the real id/pwd... just make it clear that they are required.

Comment: I know I'm being slow but without the authentication the sheet functions won't run and retrieve any data so I'm not picking up how that helps.

Comment: Have your read the part of adding a sample of the result of UrlFetchApp? It only should be representative data, no need to add real values, just same data type, similar length ...

Comment: I created a new sheet - CellarInventoryTestSheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DEtYf9JBriFjLNZziI_GyDTQ5AhybjCNgKlKXwsccXg/edit?usp=sharing).

The first tab - "Login" has description and instructions.  I also ran the sheet with the two functions and did a copy / paste special values only which shows the difference in the results.  Let me know if this is useful.

Comment: Thanks. Please bear in mind that questions on this site should be self contained. Considering this, please [edit] the question to add the link and all the relevant details i.e. the code, the sample data, etc.

Comment: It would be great to get a real answer here of course, that said, I found a solution to my original issue (the referenced question) so no longer need to use the UrlFetchApp and Utilities.parseCsv method as importData works as expected and wasn't using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) didn't add any value.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to coerce numeric text strings to numbers is to **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    value('Consumed-URLFetch Static'!A1:AT), 
    'Consumed-URLFetch Static'!A1:AT 
  ) 
)
```

Then format any date columns as **Format > Number > Date**.

See the new [Reformat](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DEtYf9JBriFjLNZziI_GyDTQ5AhybjCNgKlKXwsccXg/edit#gid=573320899) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.